# Dynamic asset_path in handlebars template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, handlebars.js

I have handlebars template (*.hbs.jst.erb) and I want to interpolate `asset_path` dynamicaly as follow:

```
{{#each subjects}}
  <img src="<%= asset_path("icons/subjects/{{slug}}.png") %>"/>
{{/each}}
```

This will render `icons/subjects/danse.png` instead of `assets/icons/subjects/danse.png` but if I put `<img src="<%= asset_path("icons/subjects/danse.png") %>"/>` it will generate the write html.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `image_path` instead of `asset_path` ?

Comment: I just did. What's weird is that it generates different path for each images but they don't work. image_path generates: `/images/icons/subjects/dance.png`

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmm! What about adding a leading slash to the path? `<%= asset_path("/icons/subjects/{{slug}}.png") %>`

Comment: Neither... But it works on my local machine if I use <%= asset_path("assets/icons/subjects/{{slug}}.png") %> but not in staging...

Comment: Hmmmmmmm - may I ask what Staging environment you're using? You may have an issue with precompiling your assets if you're using the likes of `heroku`

Comment: I'm on heroku and my assets are on amazon. The path generated on staging is right but the name of the file doesn't have the hash at the end. It's dance.png instead of dance-1299-1248-...png

Comment: Ah Okay - I think we've found your problem! Are you using the `asset-sync` gem?

Comment: Okay this is good news - let me write an answer for you -- We've had experience with this before :

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the good news is that your process is legitimate because it works locally

The problem is how Rails [uses `asset fingerprinting`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) to keep the assets in line. When using static assets (with Heroku or Amazon), it's vitally important to get all the fingerprints working correctly

The way we solved this issue was two-fold:

---

**Ensure The Assets Are Loaded Dynamically**

You've already done this with your `.erb`, but in order to get assets working correctly with fingerpriting, they have to be called dynamically so that Rails can assign the new file-name, rather than their static one

Specifically, you have to use `.scss` & `.erb` every time you want to call assets. This is a mistake many people make, as if you're using static CSS, RAILS can't call the dynamic route when it's pre-compiled. This is just something you have to bare in mind when using this process

You have done this correctly so far I think

---

**Pre-Compiling The Assets Correctly**

Our process for pre-compiling the assets is two-fold:

1. **local:** `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
2. **heroku:**

   [run the labs command to enable precompiling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)

   `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp`

   ---

   every time you deploy your app (and have changed assets, run):

   `heroku run rake assets:precompile --app [your app name]`

Comment: I did what you suggested but the asset generated are still the same. I might be missing something...!

Comment: And this also breaks fontawesome icons :/

Comment: Yep, but not on staging... I think I'll try a different approach.

Comment: I think I'll go with a class and having the images in CSS as my list is short and predictable. But thanks for the help! :)

Comment: No problem - if you need any more ideas, please let me know